# Does EndNote X3 normally run on 64-bit Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, installation, microsoft-word, packages

I can only find system requirements for [EndNote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EndNote) X4, but I only have access to a copy of X3.0.1. (I've now found the specification for EndNote X3, and it says Windows Vista or Windows XP, but most Windows XP stuff runs fine on Windows 7?)

I had EndNote X3 on Windows Vista, and then my C drive died. When I replaced it, I got 64-bit Windows 7. Now I can't re-install EndNote. When I try to install it, it keeps saying:

> This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows installer package.

It may have been installed on the E drive, so could some of the left-over files be causing trouble? I wouldn't think they'd stop the install package opening at all though? (I tried gathering all the loose files from it together in one folder. It hasn't seemed to help so far.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it seems it is. I have it working now.

I solved either by cleaning up all the files from the old installation which were floating around, or possibly by downloading it in Internet Explorer instead of Google Chrome.